# Не хочет убираться text-decoration у ссылки в виде блока

Tags: html, css

Есть такая структура `<a href="#"><div class="post"><center><span class="title">Ооооочень много ненужного текста который нужен для тестирования системы</span></center><br><hr></div></a>` не удивляейтесь почему использую `<center>`, другими никакими способами текст не хотел выравниваться по центру. Но проблема не в этом, проблема в том, что как бы я ни пытался убрать выделение текста в виде ссылки, ничего не выходит, `text-decoration` не работает и вдобавок еще `<hr>` имеет выделение в виде ссылки. Как это можно исправить? Добавлял `text-decoration` и в CSS самого `<a>`, и в `<div>`, и в `<span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  height: 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="post"><center><span class="title">Ооооочень много ненужного текста который нужен для тестирования системы</span></center><br><hr></div></a>
```

Comment: Оно же все равно есть, если нажать "Выполнить код"

Comment: А, разобрался, нужно было просто цвет тексту присвоить. Спасибо)